# how to iterate through JPA response and get values from it

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

code in the repository is

```
@Query("select divisionName, count(stundeName)FROM StudentDetails GROUP BY divisionName")
    public List<Object> getDivisionCount();
```

and code in service is

```
List <Object> countList= studentDetailsRepository.getDivisionCount();
```

now I want to iterate through countList and categories then into different categories, I tried this

```
for(int i=0;i< countList.size();i++ )
    System.out.println(countList.get(i).getClass().getDeclaredField('count'));
```

it's not working and giving an error

Comment: Share the error please, and what is the objectif of your code!

Comment: When you report an error, you should join it.

Comment: Why do you return `Object`? It should be a POJO with `divisionName` and `count` fields (and perhaps you have to alias the `count(stundeName)` in your query.

Comment: its giving java.lang.NoSuchFieldException:count

Comment: @loic I am having pojo of StudentDetails but when im using it as return type its giving me error : java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.stud.studentSystem.model.StudentDetails

Comment: Do **not** post code in comments. [Edit] your question instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate through your list of object like this and create an object array for each one in your list and then display it :

```
      for (Object object : countList){

        Object[] objArray = (Object[]) object;
        System.out.println((String)objArray[0]); // divisionName
        System.out.println((Integer)objArray[1]); // the count

      }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use a projection over the JPA response. The one option is to use the interface-baased projection. In your case the query might look like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s.divisionName AS divisionName, count(s.stundeName) AS stundeName FROM StudentDetails AS s GROUP BY s.divisionName")
public List<StudentDetails> getDivisionCount();
```

Then you need to create an interface like this:

```
public interface StudentDetails{
    String getDivisionName();
    String getStundeName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class StudentDetails { 

    private String divisionName;
    private Integer counts;
    

}
```

In Student Repository you can add Query method wuth below Query

```
@Query("SELECT new StudentDetails(s.divisionName, s.counts) FROM STUDENT s s.id = :studentId")
```

Answer (score 0):

use JPAStreamer instant of raw query in production grade implementation. read more details in official doc, [jpa_streamer](https://speedment.github.io/jpa-streamer/jpa-streamer/1.0.1/introduction/introduction.html).
Or,
Criteria Query

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: other details resource about jpaStramer you will get by Google or youtube. like, on youtube you can get some idea by https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOC97ldNWV0&ab_channel=JavaTechie